# Shipping method show options on select

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I want to create a shipping method on magento 1.9 that shows some options when the customer select this shipping method.
Its like credit card payment, when you select this option you will have the form to insert your card data.
I want to create a pickup service, when you choose the shipping method for pickup it will show the available pickup points for your address.
How can i do this?

Comment: I found it myself, you can change the file app->design->frontend->{{your_template}}->default->template->checkout->onepage->shipping_method->available.phtml

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself, you can change the file `app->design->frontend->{{your_template}}->default->template->checkout->onepage->shipping_method->available.phtml`